# Transfer float values between view controllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I wish to transfer float values from one view controller to another.
All the tutorials I can find only give examples of text transfers, not values.

I have a settings page which allows a user to click on buttons which have constant `float` values, such as `Tear = 0.13`, `Engine = 0.15`, etc. I wish to transfer these values to the root view controller, once a button 
is clicked on.

I have created a push segue, and added some code from a tutorial for the `prepareforSegue:`
of the implementation file of the source view controller.

Can anyone help me with the next step, which is the code for transferring `float` values
from the source controller to the destination (root) controller.
Here's what I have so far in `prepareforSegue:sender:` in the source view controller.

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SendInfo"]) {
         ViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
```

And this is how the `CalcViewController` implementation file looks in the `IBAction` area.

```
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.

        if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SendInfo"]) {
            ViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];}
}

- (IBAction)WT2:(id)sender {


}

- (IBAction)WT:(id)sender {

    float Tear=0.13;
}

- (IBAction)Car1:(id)sender {

    float Litre=0.13;

}

- (IBAction)Car2:(id)sender {

    float Litre=0.15;
}

- (IBAction)Car3:(id)sender {

    float Litre=0.25;
}

- (IBAction)MP1:(id)sender {

    float Net1=0.03;
}

- (IBAction)MP2:(id)sender {
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't don't store your Tear/Engine/Litre values anywhere. From what I can gather, you want to set a float value on an instance of `ViewController`. Setting a property on an object is simple.

## ViewController.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic) float litre;
@property (nonatomic) float tear;
@end
```

## CalcViewController.m

```
@interface CalcViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) float selectedLitre;
@property (nonatomic) float selectedTear;
@end

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SendInfo"]) {
        ViewController *detailViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.litre = self.selectedLitre;
        detailViewController.tear = self.selectedTear;
        //present detailViewController here...
    }
}

- (IBAction)WT:(id)sender {
   self.selectedTear = 0.13;
}

- (IBAction)Car1:(id)sender {
    self.selectedLitre = 0.13;
}
```

Comment: I notice that you created an object *detailViewController of ViewController - but the object isn't called in ViewController.h for float values. Is that correct??

Comment: Hi again, Chris! I implemented your code, but the project has crashed ever since. It seems like a memory leak, but I'm not sure where the problem lies in your code. Any suggestions? It seems that if I make a choice of one of the buttons, for Tear, or Litre, then it crashes..

Comment: @user1641906 This question has been closed. Please make a new one if you have a _specific_ question about your code.